# Are JavaScript events triggered during the onepage checkout of Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, javascript, prototype-js

I need to run some JavaScript to manipulate some fields upon checkout (auto-select a shipping option) on a Magento store. Because each stage of the onepage checkout accordion is loaded dynamically I cannot do this on page load, and instead need to do it when the relevant stage of the accordion is reached.

Is there a JavaScript event I can hook up to in order to achieve this? I would expect an event to be fired when the next step begins to load and then completes loading, but I can't find any documentation on it.

Does such a thing exist, or do I need to find a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code in your `checkout/onepage.phtml` file. This override the core **checkout gotoSetion** function

```
Checkout.prototype.gotoSection = function (section, reloadProgressBlock) {
    /*For Responsive design*/
    //Start
    // Adds class so that the page can be styled to only show the "Checkout Method" step
    if ((this.currentStep == 'login' || this.currentStep == 'billing') && section == 'billing') {
        $j('body').addClass('opc-has-progressed-from-login');
    }
    //end
    if (reloadProgressBlock) {
        this.reloadProgressBlock(this.currentStep);
    }
    this.currentStep = section;
    var sectionElement = $('opc-' + section);
    sectionElement.addClassName('allow');
    this.accordion.openSection('opc-' + section);
    /*For Responsive design*/
    //Start
    // Scroll viewport to top of checkout steps for smaller viewports
    if (Modernizr.mq('(max-width: ' + bp.xsmall + 'px)')) {
        $j('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $j('#checkoutSteps').offset().top}, 800);
    }
    //end
    if (!reloadProgressBlock) {
        this.resetPreviousSteps();
    }


// Do your customization here
  console.log(this.currentStep); 
}
```